# Filtering a Pivot Table using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have created a Pivot table using Pandas that has an index named 'names' which contains the names of countries and the columns are simply years from(1995-2008) with contain the total number of TB cases for each country. I am trying to get the highest case number years for United States of America, China and India and the associated number of cases.

Here is my code, but I am getting a

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (201,) (14,)
```

Is there an error, and also I wanted to figure out how I can display the two results at once as a dataframe.

```
countries = ['United States of America', 'China', 'India']

highest_cases_year = total_cases_pivot.loc[countries].idxmax()

print(highest_cases_year)

mask = (total_cases_pivot.index.isin(countries)) & (total_cases_pivot.columns ==    highest_cases_year)

highest_cases = total_cases_pivot.loc[mask, 'year']


print(highest_cases)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
(Select the values of v2 equal to 'A')

```py
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['v1'],columns=['v2'=='A'],values=['v3'],aggfunc='count')
```